# Is there any way to optimize Map of List?

Tags: java

given the following code?

```
final Map<String, List<E>> map = new HashMap<String, List<E>>();

List<E> list = map.get(mapKey);
if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<E>();
    map.put(mapKey, list);
}
list.add(value);
```

If there any way I can avoid the null check? But let the Map automatically create the List for me for my first time insertion?

I remember I once saw a specialized Map which is able to do this. However, I forget where I saw already :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for Guava's* [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release06/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). You may have previously heard about it when it was called "Google Collections".

[This](http://codemunchies.com/2009/11/preconditions-multimaps-and-partitioning-with-google-collections-part-4/) blog post talks a little about the MultiMap.

Comment: OK. I remember it now :) But wait! The library itself is 912KB ~ 1MB, and what I need is just this "good-to-have" feature. No thanks. My users start to complain my software download size too big. :)

Comment: @Yan - Why not just copy the interfaces/classes you need? http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.java

Comment: @Yan: Your call.  1MB doesn't seem that big to me, and Guava has a bunch of really useful stuff that you probably can/should/would use *anyway* so it's not like it's 1Mb just for this.  Anyway, at least you know your options: 1) Carry on don't the manual implementation as in your question; 2) add 1Mb to your download and use Guava; 3) Write your own version based on the Guava implementation.  Weigh up the pros and cons and choose the most attractive option overall.

Comment: If you're seriously concerned about JAR size, Guava [recommends ProGuard](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava) to filter out only the pieces you need.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)... that's what I'd do :) (And in particular, an [`ArrayListMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).)

Comment: I think it should be called ArrayListMultimap

Comment: @Yan: But the *map* part of it (which is more likely to be performance sensitive) is backed by a hashtable.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- the OP should be using an `ArrayListMultimap`, *not* a `HashMultimap`.  (`HashMultimap` maps keys to `HashSet`s.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: But we might as well keep it up to date... it's not like anyone's going to go back and need the old version...

Answer (score 1):

If you could, it might save a nanosecond and is probably not worth spending a lot of time figuring out.  If however you are trying to optimize for performance and you have so many or such big maps that this is causing performance issues, you might consider [Javolution](http://javolution.org/).  They have a fast map and fast list that perform much better than Java's default map and list.

Comment: It should be noted that even if this code is causing performance issues they are almost certainly not caused by the nullcheck, but by the allocation/construction, find and insert operations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a MultiValueMap in apache's [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of items an array might actually be faster. The overhead of more complex data types is not needed when you have a few items and a linear search helps the JVM load the items faster.